# Export/Download Mapbox map from HTML with Overlay and Markers

Tags: html, wordpress, canvas, mapbox, html2canvas

i want to build a HTML Page in which Customers can build up their personalized Maps. I used Mapbox to create this. On top of this Map there is an Overlay, also the Customer can place Markers on the Map. But i am struggeling with 2 big Questions:

1. How can i get a high Quality picture of the Map, including Overlay and Markers. Because i want to print them on posters.
2. How can i implement this logic in my webshop, so after the customer clicks save and makes a purchase, this picture will send to my server so i can print it.

https://www.cartida.de/map/ (The logic should be similar like this)
https://midi-hazel-palm.glitch.me/ (currently it looks like this)

I have written this code do download the map:

```
  function downloadMap() {
    // Get the canvas element that represents the current map view
    var canvas = map.getCanvas();

    // Create a temporary link element
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = 'map.png';
    link.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    // Add the link element to the document and click it to trigger the download
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  }
```

But the Overlay and the markers aren't added.

Thank you guys. Looking forward to hear from you.

I want a high quality Picture of Mapbox API in Html

Answer (score 0):

The [Static Images API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/static-images/) will allow you to accomplish this. [Here](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/static-images-style-params/) is a tutorial that shows a very similar use case to yours. The code should be very similar, you'll just need to make some changes to the `addLayerStyle` function to create a SymbolLayer with custom markers instead of a LineLayer as shown in the example.